# can I save my cactus?

Tags: plant-health, cactus

my Cactus is all mushy and shrunken in at the bottom and I don’t know what’s wrong, or if I can fix it. [image]

Answer (score 3):

I think the problem is too much water, and/or too frequently watered. The cactus will start to rot from roots down upwards. Soil should dry out between waterings. A cactus would normally need water every two weeks. The soil looks very wet, use soil with good drainage capacity, and a pot with drainage holes. I am not sure if this cactus is salvageable, I hope so.

Comment: It is probably beyond saving. Quite likely, all the inside is dead and rotten, and you just have the outer "skin" looking fairly normal at the top, even though it's already completely dead.

Comment: Whenever there is green stuff growing on the soil, that's a prime indicator of dead cactus nearby.